# "glib-compile-schemas not found" while trying to install File Roller

Tags: software-installation, gtk, file-roller

I wanted to install File Roller to extract .ISO file. I found it .tar.zx. After extraction I tried to install it using terminal. After using ./configure I found this error:

```
configure: error: glib-compile-schemas not found.
```

I used this command to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

but I found this error:

```
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.9.3) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not just install file-roller using the `apt-get`?

Comment: Compiling stuff from source, while it is sometimes easy, is not the stuff of "noobs"... +1 Braiam. Why aren't you using the file-roller from the Software Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to compile file-roller from source. It's already installed, anyway. You can mount it and then copy the files somewhere:

```
sudo mount -o loop <image>.iso /<mountpoint>
```

For example, if you want mount it (so you can see all the files) in `/home/Downloads/mountpoint`, which is just a folder named "mountpoint" you created in your Downloads folder, you would paste the following, with a space at the end, into the terminal:

```
sudo mount -o loop
```

Then you would literall *click and drag* the .iso file from your file manager into the terminal window so the file's path appears. Then, after that and a space, you would type `~/Downloads/mountpoint` so it looks rather like:

```
sudo mount -o loop <the name of your image>.iso ~/Downloads/mountpoint
```

Then you would go into that folder with the file manager and do what you need to do. Depending on what that is, you may want to copy the files over to another directory.

When you have a filesystem such as a partition on a USB thumb drive or an .iso file (which can be used as a volume), you must mount it in order to get the OS to see the files.

Comment: What is mount point? Excuse me I am noob

Comment: I made my answer a little more clear... let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I mounted the image successfully, but I still want to know how to fix the above problem

Comment: To do that, you need some future version of gtk+, at least 3.9.3, which isn't even available in the Saucy repos. You'll have to download it from [here](http://www.gtk.org/download/index.php) and compile that in turn, from source. It may require that you compile even more things from source... often it can turn into a wild goose chase of compiling and next thing you know you've got a whole new system supporting the one program.